# css - float & align to the bottom of an element

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

How can I align at the same time: `float:right` elements `B & C` next to `element A`, and `align` `element B` to the bottom of `element A`, and `element C` to the top:

When I add the float to `elements B & C`, these two elements are aligned to the top of `element A`, what I want is shown on the next image:

[image: float & alignement]

**PS:** `element A` doesnt have a fixed size.

Comment: will u share your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: If if element A,B and C have fixed heights then you could use margin-top on the B-element to bridge the gap between C and B. 

So if A height = 300px and B and C are 100px add margin-top:100px to the B element to make the offset.

Comment: Floated elements always go as high up as possible, floating an element “to the bottom” is not possible. You will have to find another approach.

Comment: `element A` doesnt have a fixed size (A is an image).

Comment: You may need to position B and C absolutely in relation to A. I do not think this can be done with floats.

Comment: What is the order of the divs? Can you change it?

Comment: yes I can modify the order of A, B & C (now it is A then C the B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that this can be done with floats. I would try nesting div C and B within A, and then positioning them absolutely in relation to A.

So something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="a">a
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a {
    margin-left: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
.b, .c {
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
}
.b {
     bottom: 0;
}
.c {
     top: 0;
}
```

See [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9S5t/) example.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="elementA">A
    <div class="elementB">B</div>
    <div class="elementC">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.elementA{
    width: 400px;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.elementB{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.elementC{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -200px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

You can also set the hight of element A in %.
Hope thats what you're after.
[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/QP6Je/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you can use JQuery and not only CSS this can do the trick:

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx7pN/)**

You can calculate the height of each element dynamically and then add a top-margin to element b.

```
element b margin top = height of a - (height of b + height of c)
```

HTML

```
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="left-column">
    <div class="c">C</div><br />
    <div class="b">B</div><br />
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    var ah = $('div.a').height();
    var bh = $('div.b').height();
    var ch = $('div.c').height();
    $('div.b').css('margin-top',ah-bh-ch + 'px');
});
```

CSS

```
.left-column{
    float: right;
}

.a{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #7E0C89;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.b{
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F4CBF7;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.c{  
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #BF72E9;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```